# Python - Json to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have the next issue when converting Json to Dataframe with json_normalize

```
 File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1273, in 
 pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects
 OverflowError: long too big to convert
```

The code is:

```
def getFinanceHistoricalStockFromByma(tickerList): 
     dataFrameHistorical = pd.DataFrame()  
     for item in tickerList:
         url = 'https://www.byma.com.ar/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_historico_simbolo&simbolo=' + item + '&fecha=01-01-2015'
         print url          
         response = requests.get(url)
         if response.content : print 'ok info Historical Stock'
         data = response.json()                
         dfItem = jsonToDataFrame(data)
         dataFrameHistorical = dataFrameHistorical.append(dfItem, ignore_index=True)
     return dataFrameHistorical


 def jsonToDataFrame(jsonStr):    
     #sizeInfo(jsonStr)
     return json_normalize(jsonStr)
```

Is there json_normalize deprecated or in has lenght issues? the jsonStr has 3200 bytes

Thanks!!!!

Comment: It doesn't sound like it has a problem converting the whole json due to length. But a field that is a numerical number is too big to convert to a long int.

Comment: are you trying to just take the json and make a dataframe out of it? have you looked at [`read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: Thanks! MattR. I{ve tried with read_json() without lucky. In this case, the error is "Raise vañue error <type: List>"

Comment: Thenks Orenshi, i^ve found in response a long value :S mybe i can convert that. Waht do you recommend?